# How to insert a pandas dataframe into elasticsearch with the column types?

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch

I want index a **pandas** data frame into **elasticsearch** server. One of my columns is **Timestamp** and some of them are numbers and some are string. How can I import this type of dataframe in elasticsearch. I know that I can use **_bulk API** but I don't know How exactly?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('week1_features.csv',index_col=0)
df.head()
```

```html
<html>
<div>
  <table border="1" class="dataframe">
    <thead>
      <tr style="text-align: right;">
        <th></th>
        <th>srcIp</th>
        <th>collectionTimestamp</th>
        <th>destinationBytes</th>
        <th>destinationPackets</th>
        <th>sourceBytes</th>
        <th>sourcePackets</th>
        <th>hour</th>
        <th>WeekDay</th>
        <th>FlowNumber</th>
        <th>dstPort</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>0</th>
        <td>1.180.189.18</td>
        <td>2017-04-12 12:08:00</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>60.0</td>
        <td>1.0</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td>1.180.189.18</td>
        <td>2017-04-12 12:08:30</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <td>1.186.141.30</td>
        <td>2017-04-12 07:26:00</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>60.0</td>
        <td>1.0</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>3</th>
        <td>1.191.82.68</td>
        <td>2017-04-13 03:05:00</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>60.0</td>
        <td>1.0</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <td>1.214.141.149</td>
        <td>2017-04-10 04:19:30</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>0.0</td>
        <td>136.0</td>
        <td>1.0</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By this function you can insert a pandas dataframe into elasticsearch easily. But for time column you have to apply map to time fieldName before insert dataframe.

```
def insertDataframeIntoElastic(dataFrame,index='index', typ = 'test', server = 'http://192.168.11.148:9200',
                           chunk_size = 2000):
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-ndjson', 'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'}
    records = dataFrame.to_dict(orient='records')
    actions = ["""{ "index" : { "_index" : "%s", "_type" : "%s"} }\n""" % (index, typ) +json.dumps(records[j])
                    for j in range(len(records))]
    i=0
    while i<len(actions):
        serverAPI = server + '/_bulk' 
        data='\n'.join(actions[i:min([i+chunk_size,len(actions)])])
        data = data + '\n'
        r = requests.post(serverAPI, data = data, headers=headers)
        print r.content
        i = i+chunk_size
```